# the finite difference operator is bounded in the sequence space

Tags: functional-analysis

For $h>0$, we define

$$
(\delta_h(x))_j = \frac{x_{j+1}-x_j}{h}
$$

which is the finite difference operator for $x\in l^2(\mathbb{N})$. I want to show that this $\delta_h$ is a bounded operator, i.e.

$$
\|\delta_hx\|_{l^2} \leq M_h \|x\|_{l^2}.
$$

I tried to write out

$$
\begin{aligned}
\|\delta_hx\|_{l^2}^2 &= \sum_j |\frac{x_{j+1}-x_j}{h}|^2 = \frac{1}{h^2}\sum_j|x_{j+1}-x_j|^2\\
&=\frac{1}{h^2}\sum_j|x_{j+1}^2+x_j^2 - 2x_{j+1}x_{j}|\\
&\leq \frac{1}{h^2}\sum_j|x_{j+1}^2|+|x_j^2| +| 2x_{j+1}x_{j}|\\
\end{aligned}
$$
but not sure how to proceed forward.

Comment: Apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for the last term.

Comment: how are you going to argue the relation between $x_{j+1}$ and $x_j$?

Answer (score 1):

By Minkowski's inequality (the triangle inequality for $\ell^2$) we have
$$\|(x_{j+1}-x_j)_{j \ge 1}\| \le \|(x_{j+1})_{j \ge 1}\|+\|x\| \le 2\|x\| \,,$$
so
$$\|\delta_h(x)\| \le \frac{2}{h} \|x\| \,.$$
To see the constant $2/h$ is optimal, consider a vector $x$ of the form
$(1,-1,1,-1,\ldots,1,-1,0,0,\ldots)$ that has $2n$ nonzero entries.
Then $\|x\|^2= 2n$. The vector
$$   \delta_h(x)=\frac{1}{h}(-2,2,-2,2\ldots,-2,1,0,0,\ldots)$$
also has $2n$ nonzero entries, and
$$\|\delta_h(x)\|^2= \frac{1}{h^2}(8n-3)= \frac{8n-3}{8n} \cdot\frac{4}{h^2} \|x\|^2 \,.
$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality

Comment: how do you argue $x_{j+1} < x_j$. the first line should be $x_j$ rather than $x$ right?

Comment: The $\ell_2$ norm of the vector $(x_{j+1})_{j \ge 1}$ is at most the norm of $x=(x_j)_{j \ge 1}$

Comment: thanks but which theorem tells that?

Comment: $x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2+ \ldots \le x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+ \ldots$

Comment: what if now we have $x_{j+1}-x_{j-1}$, then it's seems we don't have the inequality to bound $x_j$

Comment: It works fine with $x_{j-1}$. Do you understand the answer to your original question? If so, do you know how to accept an answer?

Comment: i see why 2/h is optimal and how $x_j$ bounds $x_{j+1}$. but if it's $x_{j+1}-x_{j-1}$, then $\|Tx\| \leq 2\|x_{j-1}\|$ but by definition, we need $\|x_j\|$ on the right hand side

Comment: First, do you agree my answer actually answers your original question? If so, you should accept the answer. Second, what is the vector $(x_{j-1})_{j \ge 1}$ when $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$? The usual convention is that it will be $(0,x_1,x_2 \ldots)$ that has the same norm as $x$.

Comment: thanks! i was thinking of $x_0$ instead of 0 at the first position of $x_{j-1}$.

Comment: Does your sequence start with $ x_1 $ or $x_0$?

Comment: in examples given in class, they all start with $x_0$